How can i send a Varible from a controller to another controler?
Hi community is me again did you know how can i call a variable from a controller to another i say this cause I'm trying to have the user from the index to make all the query's that the user is going to use when he is log into the app this is my controller that i use to catch the user i try using view Data or View Bag but that doesn't work I also use session to use try to send it to another controller and doesn't work to so any one know how can i send this info or maybe have a link that can explain me that?
        UserN = Request.Form("userN")
        password = Request.Form("password")
        login = Request.Form("Index")
        Message = ""
        role = ""
        name = ""
        'Query para validar usuario en base de datos
        Dim qry = " SELECT IDEmployee, Password, Role " &
                            " FROM IntranetSecurity " &
                            " WHERE (IDEmployee= '" & UserN & "') "
        cmd.CommandText = qry
        cnn.Open()
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                Username = reader.GetString(0)
                DBPassword = reader.GetString(1)
                role = reader.GetString(2)
                If DBPassword = password AndAlso (role = "HSEAdmin" OrElse role = "NEO") Then
                    Session("Admin") = "True"
                    ViewData("role") = role
                    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "SesionAdmin")
                ElseIf DBPassword = password Then
                    Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Sesion")
                End If
            Else
                Message = "Usuario o Contraseña no válidos"
            End If
        End Using
        ViewData("Message") = Message
        ViewData("UserN") = UserN
        cnn.Close()
        Return View()
    End Function ```

as you can see, I declare the variable that received the user in the login then the query uses the user to validate if the user exists into the data base after that validate the role, then redirect the user using the Role to the app dashboard but I won't that the dashboard being personalize with the username.

i try using this ViewData("UserN") = UserN and anothers that i mention before 


Hi is me again i found how to do it i let the solution here you can fix this using this line of code obviously adapting to your Oun code first we declare our list Dim ReportList As List(Of IntranetSecurity) = New List(Of IntranetSecurity)() then we create the variable were we going to save your data  UserN = reader.GetString(0) dont forget to declare first that variable   Dim UserN As String then we use  the link action Dim link As String = Url.Action("Index", "SesionAdmin", New With {.UserN = UserN}) and finaly we return our link  Return Redirect(link) i hope this will help some one
